# Mixing addition and subtraction with logical NOT

Tags: boolean-logic

I found some exercises where you combine n-bit 2's complement values in different ways and simplify the output where possible. (Their practice exercises use 16-bit, but that's irrelevant).

Eg:

`!(!x&!y) == x|y`

`0 & y, negate the output == -1`

I'm having no problem applying De Morgan's laws with the examples using AND, OR, and NOT but I am having difficulty using NOT with + and -

Eg:

`!(!x+y) == x-y`

`!(y-1) == -y`

How does NOT distribute?

**Edit:** responding to comments: I realize this is a bitwise NOT. My question is: in algebraic terms, how does it distribute as per algebra? [Example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity)

Comment: Is that bit-wise `NOT` or the "bang" operator?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm surprised nobody's edited the `!`s into `~`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2's complement numbers when you bitwise NOT them it is the same as saying the negative of the number minus 1, so `!x` is equivalent to `-x - 1` where x can be a single variable or an expression.

Starting with `!(!x+y)`, well `!x` is going to be `-x - 1` so then it is `!(-x - 1 + y)` which becomes `-(-x - 1 + y) - 1` which simplifies to `x - y`.

And for `!(y-1)`, that becomes `-(y - 1) - 1 = -y + 1 - 1 = -y`.